# converting parquet file to pandas and then querying gives error

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I am trying to query a dataframe for an average of a column, and I converted a parquet file to pandas to do this. I'm getting the error TypeError('Could not convert %s to numeric' % str(x)) which seems to refer to the word "Age" in the column.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
         _c0     _c1  _c2    
    0  RecId   Class  Age   
    1      1    1st    29   
    2      2    1st     2   
    3      3    1st    30
```

My code is:

```
    import pyarrow 
    import pandas
    import pyarrow.parquet as pq

    df = pq.read_table("file.parquet").to_pandas()
    average_age = df["_c2"].mean()
```

I tried using

```
    df = df(skiprows=1)
```

but that gives the error "TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable"

How can I either skip over the row with "Age" in it or remove it, and is this related to it being read from a parquet file or is this a straight up Pandas issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use pandas index to remove the first row:

```
df = df.iloc[1:,:]
```

Comment: That worked for what I asked, thanks very much. Unfortunately I realized that wasn't the problem after all. There are some NA markings in some of the ages and that must be what is doing it. I'll research how to get rid of those or reask in another thread.